# App pool won't recylce in IIS 6.0

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, application-pool

On IIS 6.0 I have configured an app pool to recycle at 7am in the morning but I am not sure if it recycled as nothing is logged in the system viewer logs. Any ideas

[image]

And is there a way we can get an alert when pool recycles?

Comment: Maybe this could work: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/87892589-4eda-4003-b4ac-3879eac4bf48.mspx?mfr=true

Comment: I can see a few pool recycles at different times on different days in past few days. But nothing happened since I set the recycle time to 7am

Answer (score 0):

There will be a log entry only if the recycle does happen.

Note that because IIS has other mechanisms to monitor the worker processes (such as idle shutdown), at 7am there might be no worker process at all for IIS to recycle. Then there will be no log entry.

Make sure you check IIS log files and confirm what exactly happens at 7am. Process Monitor is a good tool for you to in fact capture the activities and analyze.